# Integral on a contour curve

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Find the line integral along curve $C$ of $[f(z)]^2=z$ where $f(1)=1$.

Here is curve c: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNrIA.jpg (Sorry for the blur, the points are $1$ and $e$)

How can I solve this? I am lost. Is $f(z)= z^{1/2}$? If so, is $f(1) = 1$ telling us the radius in the beginning is $1$? Which method do we use to solve this and how can you tell? *Note: No residue method.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(z)$ is one of the square roots of $z$. Since $f(1)=1$, we deduce that $f(z)=\sqrt z$. Since $f$ is continuous and has a primitive in the curve $C$, which is $F(z)=\frac{2}{3}z^{\frac{3}{2}}$, you can calculate the integral simply by:

$$\int_{C}f(z)dz=F(e)-F(1)=\frac{2}{3}(e^{\frac{2}{3}}-1)$$

Comment: Suppose that $C$ would wind three times around $0$. Your argument would then produce a wrong answer.

Comment: I made the assumption that f is given by the formula $f(z)=\sqrt z$ for all $z$ in the curve. In that case, it is continuous and has primitive in every $z$ in the curve and we can use Barrow. Under this assumption, the answer doesn't depend on the number of loops around $0$

Comment: The formula $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$ does not make sense globally without accompagning explanations, let alone the idea of a primitive of $f$. See the edit to my answer, where a $\gamma'$ making three turns around $0$ is considered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting the problem as follows: In the neighborhood of the starting point of $\gamma$ we should assume $f(z):={\rm pv}\sqrt{z}$. Proceeding along $\gamma$ the function $f$ is understood as analytic continuation of this original "germ". The curve $\gamma$ may safely be replaced by the concatenation of
$$\gamma_1:\quad t\mapsto e^{it}\qquad(0\leq t\leq 4\pi)$$
and
$$\gamma_2:\quad x\mapsto x\qquad(1\leq x\leq e)\ .$$
Along $\gamma_1$ we obviously have
$$f\bigl(z(t)\bigr)=e^{it/2}\ .$$
After two full turns around $0$ the the analytic continuation of $f$ has  arrived again at $f(z):={\rm pv}\sqrt{z}$. It follows that along $\gamma_2$ we simply have $$f\bigl(z(x)\bigr)=\sqrt{x}\ .$$
In this way we obtain
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\>dz=\int_0^{4\pi} e^{it/2}\>ie^{it}\>dt+\int_1^e \sqrt{x}\>dx={2\over3}(e^{2/3}-1)\ .\tag{1}$$
It may be of interest to consider also the analogous curve $\gamma'$ winding *three* times around $0$ before drifting off to $e$. At the end of $\gamma_1'$ the analytic continuation of  $f$  arrives at $f(z)=-{\rm pv}\sqrt{z}$, and instead of $(1)$ we obtain
$$\int_{\gamma'}f(z)\>dz=\int_0^{6\pi} e^{it/2}\>ie^{it}\>dt+\int_1^e(-\sqrt{x})\>dx=-{4\over3}-{2\over3}(e^{2/3}-1)\ .$$